# Life time of DbContext in a long-running process

Tags: entity-framework

Say I have a long-running process (e.g. Windows service) which needs to access a database from multiple threads.

DbContext is not thread safe, also it is a good idea not to keep it around for a long time (seems that an accepted best practice in the web environment is to create a new context for each request).

Based on EF docs, *Contexts are expected to be short-lived and discarded, and as such have been implemented to be very lightweight and reutilize metadata whenever possible*, so it seems like creating a new DB context for each database operation might be a way to go under these circumstances, but it does seem a bit excessive.

Thoughts?

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: @Sampath There's none at the moment. Deciding on a best way to write it.

Comment: Keeping DbContext in a long run is not a good idea - memory leaks, overflow are possible, plus change tracking might bring you funky results. Creating and disposing DbContext as you need is a pretty good idea

Comment: Also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Comment: @raderick Thanks for the link, its useful.

Comment: "*Thoughts?*" pretty much brands this question as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

Short-running, for sure, but not only because of DB considerations, also because of application architecture: if your architecture is Clean Code (as per Bob Martin), a Website or Windows Service would not know anything about the database, they would simply create an Application Service as & when required.  The Application Service(s) should be responsible for controlling the lifecycle of the database session, and all the bits they get from it.  Works really well for me.

Comment: Why should an application know more about the database when the context lives longer? You only shift the problem from context life cycle to Application Service life cycle. I don't think the context's lifespan itself has any bearing on separation of concerns.