# Avoiding memory leak from a list returned by an entity framework query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, memory-leaks

I would like to know how I can ensure that memory allocated to a list of objects will be freed.

I have a method in a c# .NET program which returns a list of objects filtered depending upon a number of criteria. The method is written so that this filtering cannot be performed all in one query therefore it keeps recreating the list as the filter is refined.

I strongly believe that this method is responsible for a memory as after several calls to this method the users are reporting a crash with an Out of Memory Exception.

The code is like this:

```
    private List<Things> GetMatchingThings(DataContext context, string number, 
                                       DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, 
                                       string otherNumber, string orderNumber, 
                                       string shiftNumber, 
                                       bool includeDeletedThings)
{

    List<Things> thingList =  context.Set<Things>()  
                                     .Where(th => th.Number == number &&
                                            th.FinishDateTime.HasValue && 
                                            !th.IsRunning)  
                                     .ToList();

    if (thingList != null && thingList.Count > 0 )
    {
          var filteredList = thingList.FindAll(th => th.StartDateTime.Date >= startDate.Date 
                                                     && 
                                                     th.StartDateTime.Date <= endDate.Date);
          thingList = filteredList;
    }

    if (thingList != null && thingList.Count > 0 && otherNumber.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
    {
          var filteredList = thingList.FindAll(th => th.OtherNumber.Equals(otherNumber));
          thingList = filteredList;
    }

    if (thingList != null && thingList.Count > 0 && orderNumber.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
    {
          var filteredList = thingList.FindAll(th => th.orderNumber != null &&
                                            th.orderNumber.Equals(orderNumber));
          thingList = filteredList;
    }

    // Other repetitions of the filtering above for the remaining search criteria

    if (thingList != null && thingList.Count > 0)
    {
                thingList.Sort((x,y) => y.StartDateTime.CompareTo(x.StartDateTime));
    }

    return thingList;
    }
```

The filtering is done in stages like this because some of the search criteria are optional, only the start date will always be included. So the initial list is found and then filtered further depending upon which other criteria have been provided.

However, I am assuming that the FindAll method calls used create a new list but then when this new list is assigned to thingList the original memory occupied by thingList is not being reclaimed.

As far as I know calling thingList.Clear() after each new filteredList is created would not help since Clear just removed items from the list but does not reclaim the memory.

The Thing object also contains a property which is unmanaged.

My question is how can I

a) Find a way to free the memory allocated to thingList and filteredList in the intermediate queries

or

b) Rewrite the original Where query to do this all in one go given that some of the search criteria may not be needed. Is there a way of using a wildcard in a Query like this as there is in SQL, e.g. .Where th.orderNumber.Equals("%")

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to mark start and end of a code snippet so that it all goes in to the shaded area

Comment: Any line starting with 4 spaces will be marked as code. Select the lines of code and press CTRL+K to add 4 spaces to all these lines.

Comment: what makes you think you have a memory leak, what tools did you use?

Comment: Are you reusing the `DbContext`? ...

Comment: @TheGeneral "after several calls to this method the users are reporting a crash with an Out of Memory Exception"

Comment: C# uses a garbage collector. If a value is no longer assigned to any variable or field, it will be collected by the GC. In the above code, allocated lists (except the one returned) will be cleared in one of the next GC cycles. Creating a memory "leak" in C# is fairly hard, generally, it means you're storing a lot of large data in lists you did not mean to store.

Comment: Which function are directly before and after this one? What do you do with the list afterward?

Comment: The DBContext is passed in as a parameter context. It is being used in the rest of the application.

Comment: To add some more weight on @ikkentim's comment: this piece of code doesn't seem to have a memory leak. Although passing in the `DataContext context` is suspicious and if you store all the results in a big monster-list then you are doomed.

Comment: The `DbContext` has a change tracker. It is wise to recreate the `DbContext`as needed, and hence: do not use the same one throughout the application

Comment: Suspicious indeed

Comment: Most likely the db context holds all entities - see comment/question by @Stefan

Comment: The list that is returned is used to create a drop-down list of choices to a user so they can select which Thing object to use. Actually I don't think anything is then ever down to empty that list. Would assigning null to the list do that?

Comment: Yes, or reassigning will do as well. With normal managed object you don't need to free memory explicitly, [although: if the objects are `IDisposable` I always advise to use it]

Comment: One of the reasons I thought that this reassigning of the lists might be the cause was because we had a similar problem in another bit of this code a few months ago. A method with a complicated Where clause which returned a list of these objects was rewritten so that it did a less complicated Where to return a list of objects and then that list was refined further similar to the above. We soon started to get numerous OutofMemory exceptions but when the code was reverted to its  earlier form they stopped happening. Hence I assumed this was a similar situation

Answer (score 1):

C# uses a garbage collector. If a value is no longer assigned to any variable or field, it will be collected by the GC. In the above code, allocated lists (except the one returned) will be cleared in one of the next GC cycles. Creating a memory "leak" in C# is fairly hard, generally, it means you're storing a lot of large data in lists you did not mean to store

If the list contains a lot of data and you do not want to have to copy it over and over, you could use LINQ:

```
context.Set<Things>()  
    .Where(th => th.Number == number && th.FinishDateTime.HasValue && !th.IsRunning)  
    .Where(th => th.StartDateTime.Date >= startDate.Date && th.StartDateTime.Date <= endDate.Date)
    .Where(th => th.OtherNumber.Equals(otherNumber))
    .Where(th => th.orderNumber != null && th.orderNumber.Equals(orderNumber))
    .OrderBy((x,y) => y.StartDateTime.CompareTo(x.StartDateTime))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ikkentim I have not seen the .Where clause repeated like that before. Thank you I might be able to use that to refine the query more in one go.

Comment: The general idea here seems to be the best approach. Though I do think OP wanted to append his where queries conditionally. Another additional problem: Since you moved the query to EF not all functions might be translated like the date time Comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following to rule out any DB/changetracker issues:

```
//note: renamed dbContext variable
private List<Things> GetMatchingThings(DataContext doNotUseContext, string number, 
                                   DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, 
                                   string otherNumber, string orderNumber, 
                                   string shiftNumber, 
                                   bool includeDeletedThings)
{
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
    {
        //your original code here
    }
}
```

The `using` will dispose the context properly, and by using a new DbContext you ensure a fresh new object. There are some issues with keeping the DbContext alive:

See:

[Life time of DbContext in a long-running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113035/life-time-of-dbcontext-in-a-long-running-process)

[Should the DbContext in EF have a short life span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947970/should-the-dbcontext-in-ef-have-a-short-life-span)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

[Why re-initiate the DbContext when using the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647912/why-re-initiate-the-dbcontext-when-using-the-entity-framework)

Comment: Stefan I appreciate the advice about not keeping DbContext alive longer than necessary and I am aware that this is generally recommended. Unfortunately in the way this application has been written the DbContext is a global variable that gets reused widely. The application is a WPF Windows Form and the global DbContext is used to populate the form and is then used for any updates. With hindsight it would be good to restructure this application so that we do not use the same DbContext like this but unfortunately that will require an extensive rewrite which is not possible in the short term.

Comment: I understand; nevertheless you could try this in order to isolate your issue with the current code; if it help, maybe the urge to change the use of the DbContext will grow.